# Hydrogen Atom output window issues

Tags: atom-editor, hydrogen

I have Hygdrogen installed for my Atom editor. It was working fine till yesterday.

When I run using shift+enter, the output window displays the result as per normal:

[image: screenshot 1 shows the normal working of hydrogen. The output window is displayed]

However, when I close the output window, the window closes, leaving behind a huge space between code line 1 & code line 2:

[image: screenshot 2 shows the state after closing window. See the big space between code line 1 and code line 2. After this state my entire coding gets messed up.]

After that, all my coding lines are disrupted. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Inserted images from OP's link

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is due to a bug in Atom 1.19.6 and 1.20.0-beta6.

Upgrading to Atom 1.19.7 or 1.20.0 will fix your issue.